# LWC: Alignment lost when using Name in Lightning-record-edit-form

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds, lightning-recordeditform

I have a requirement to mimic the create contact form in LWC. For this, I am using `lightning-rec-rd-edit-form`. When I use `Name` field, it consumes 4 rows as it has Salutation, First name, Middle name, Last name. Thus, when I try to add the columns row-wise(next to FirstName), the fields are not getting added while it is getting added below.

For example,

[image: Lightning-record-edit-form]

I want Address field to appear next to the First name. Can someone please let me know what modifications I need to do.

Below is the LWC code:

```
<template>
    
    <h3 class="label slds-truncate slds-p-around_x-small slds-theme_shade">
        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Information"> Contact Information </span>
    </h3>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name="Contact"
    record-id="0038I00000LQAR"
    >
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Email"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="CNG_Address__c"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

PS: Please let me know if there is any open repos where I can get the exact replica of the create form in the LWC. **I do not want to use lightning-record-form**

Comment: Name is not a single writable field on Contact object, like you have seen it compromises of other name fields. To get a proper UI; use Firstname, Lastname, Middlename and Salutation as a separate inputs respectively.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @Raul, you need to have separate fields for FirstName, LastName, MiddleName & Salutation.

For 2 column layout using slds , you can use below code :

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field class="slds-col" field-name="Salutation"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field class="slds-col" field-name="Email"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field class="slds-col" field-name="FirstName"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field class="slds-col" field-name="CNG_Address__c"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="MiddleName"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/

Also , if you do not want to use `lightning-record-edit-form`, you need to use `lightning-input` with apex method.
Related answer. :[Update records in LWC using Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383706/update-records-in-lwc-using-apex)

For only record creation , you can use standard functions as shown [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write)

Github repo: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsCreateRecord

Comment: Did not understand the reason for downvote ? Whoever downvoted , it would be good if you could provide some feedback.